# How to know which plugin is adding the "run" task in gradle

Tags: java, gradle, spring-boot, gradlew

I have a gradle-based project that doesn't implement the "application" plugin, but somehow the "run" task runs perfectly when i just write on the console

```
./gradlew run
```

I've been looking among the plugins and I can't find which one is adding the "run" task.

- Is there a way to list the tasks defined by each plugin available in
  my project?
- Is is possible for a plugin being adding the task by
  transitively adding another plugin? How do I know which one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
gradle -q tasks --all
```

which will show all the tasks as well as the plugin responsible for each task.  This is covered in the section titled "Listing tasks" in the [Gradle manual](https://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/tutorial_gradle_command_line.html).

Comment: Thank you, but it doesn't specify the plugin name. Unless it is there, but the documentation don't say anything about it.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the `spring-boot` gradle plugin? If so, it [imports the `application` plugin](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/v1.2.1.RELEASE/spring-boot-tools/spring-boot-gradle-plugin/src/main/groovy/org/springframework/boot/gradle/SpringBootPlugin.groovy#L47) to provide support for the `bootRun` task.